# Scala: Mis-using traits, gives runtime error

Tags: scala, traits

Sorry for the broad topic; I'm just not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have a class structure

```
trait BaseType {
  val property: String
}

trait MiddleTrait extends BaseType {
  val myProperty = property.length.toString
  def userProperty() = {
    myProperty
  }
}

object Top extends MiddleTrait {
  val property = "value given here"
}
```

Which compiles; but hits a run time error - `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class controllers.test.Top$`

Updating MiddleTrait to `def myProperty = property.length.toString` it will run fine.

I looking to understand the theory behind this better so I could predict the error without seeing it fail at run time first

Thanks

Comment: The theory is here http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I paste your code into a Scala 2.11.6 REPL I don't get any errors at first. Trying to access `myProperty` will result in a `NullPointerException`

```
scala> Top.myProperty
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at MiddleTrait$class.$init$(<console>:12)
  ... 35 elided
```

The `NullPointerException` is thrown because `MiddleTrait` gets initialized before `Top` at which point `property` is still `null` ([see spec on template evaluation](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#templates)). If you turn `myProperty` into a function, the error goes away because the function is called on the fully initialized `Top`.

The error you quoted comes up for me when I try to access `myProperty` again, after the `NullPointerException`

```
scala> Top.myProperty
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class Top$
  ... 33 elided
```